# How to measure Python import loading times/latencies in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, module, profiling

How to measure Python modules' `import` loading times/latencies in `AppEngine`?

I want to receive such report:

```
module_name -> 1s
...
```

I have implemented/tested some solutions based on `sys.path_hooks` and `__import__` patching but it works with pure Python but not with `AppEngine`.

Can anyone with experience in `AppEngine`/Python or pure Python suggest/share some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such solution to track times on App Engine - not fully threadsafe - what you think?

module.py

```
# coding=utf-8
## \authors Cezary K. Wagner

from threading import Lock

__indent = 0
__patched = False

def logImports():
  global __patched
  if __patched == True:
    return

  import time
  import logging
#  import inspect
  import __builtin__

  original__import__ = __builtin__.__import__

  def patched__import__(name, *args):
    global __indent
    lock = Lock()
    lock.acquire()
    spaces = ' ' * (__indent * 2)
#    callerFrame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
#    moduleName = callerFrame.f_globals['__name__']
#    lineNumber = callerFrame.f_lineno
#    logging.debug('%simport start %s %s:%s.' % (spaces, name, moduleName, lineNumber))
    __indent += 1
    start = time.clock()
    try:
      module = original__import__(name, *args)
      delta = time.clock() - start
    # import could fail
    finally:
      lock.release
      __indent -= 1
    if delta >= 1.0:
      logging.debug('%simport end %s in %ss' % (spaces, name, delta))
    return module

  __builtin__.__import__ = patched__import__
  __patched = True
```

usage.py

```
from module import logImports
logImports()

import math
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Engine caches imports](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#App_Caching) and this is probably messing things up for path_hooks.
Since imported are caches they usually won't cause any major problems in the production environment.

Comment: The problem is latency with load it could cause **deadline exceed exception** since 60s time limit - as you said **if it loads it will be fast** - problem is with loading latencies.

If you use a lot of modules could be problem since each could do some not lazy caching (prepare data before it need).

Comment: You can still test it locally, and improvement that you will do locally will also effect on the server.

Comment: Sure but timee is money and results will be different than on production server - not worthy - I do such solution ...